# c udp socket not receiving/sending correctly

Tags: c++, c, sockets, udp

I am currently experiencing some trouble while testing UDP sockets.
So I have 2 c programs, one sends and receives, the other receives and sends a message.

Here is send_recv.c:

```c
#define PORT    1010

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
        int socketInfo, opt;
        struct sockaddr_in server;
        char msgOut[30], msgIn[30];

        opt = 1;

        printf("Input message: ");
        fgets(msgOut, 30, stdin);

        socketInfo = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
        if(socketInfo < 0) {
                perror("socket error");
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        if(setsockopt(socketInfo, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR | SO_REUSEPORT, &opt, sizeof(opt))) {
                perror("setsockopt failed");
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        server.sin_family = AF_INET;
        server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
        server.sin_port = htons(PORT);

        if(bind(socketInfo, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server)) < 0) {
                perror("bind error");
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        if(connect(socketInfo, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server)) < 0) {
                perror("connection error");
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        puts("connected");

        send(socketInfo, msgOut, strlen(msgOut), 0);

        puts("sleeping for 5");
        sleep(5);

        puts("message sent");

        recv(socketInfo, msgIn, sizeof(msgIn), 0);

        printf("received msg: %s\n", msgIn);

        close(socketInfo);

        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

And here is recv_send.c:

```c
#define PORT    1010

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
        int socketInfo, opt;
        struct sockaddr_in server;
        char msgOut[30], msgIn[30];

        opt = 1;

        socketInfo = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
        if(socketInfo < 0) {
                perror("socket error");
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        if(setsockopt(socketInfo, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR | SO_REUSEPORT, &opt, sizeof(opt))) {
                perror("setsockopt failed");
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        server.sin_family = AF_INET;
        server.sin_port = htons(PORT);
        server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

        if(bind(socketInfo, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server)) < 0) {
                perror("bind error");
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        if(connect(socketInfo, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server)) < 0) {
                perror("connection error");
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        puts("connected");

        recv(socketInfo, msgIn, sizeof(msgIn), 0);

        printf("received msg: %s\n", msgIn);

        printf("Input message: ");
        fgets(msgOut, 30, stdin);

        send(socketInfo, msgOut, strlen(msgOut), 0);

        puts("message sent");

        close(socketInfo);

        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The problem is that the receive program never receives anything, and the send program sends and then just receives the message it already received.

The output of send_rcv is this:

```
Input message: hello there
connected
message sent
received msg: hello there
```

and the output of rcv_send is this:

```
connected
(ctrl+z) Job 6, 'sudo ./rcv_send' has stopped
```

Another problem is that when I don't run the program with sudo it just says this: `bind error: Permission denied`

Comment: I don't think you're allowed to have two sockets bound to the same port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that both endpoints are listening on the same port while running on the same machine, and you have both sides sending to `INADDR_ANY`.

Also, port numbers below 1024 are privileged ports and therefore require root access to bind to.

Use a different port (1024 or higher) for each side of the connection, and choose a specific IP address to connect to.  For example:

```
#define LOCAL_PORT    1100
#define REMOTE_PORT   1101

...

struct sockaddr_in local, remote;

local.sin_family = AF_INET;
local.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
local.sin_port = htons(LOCAL_PORT);
remote.sin_family = AF_INET;
remote.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_LOOPBACK);
remote.sin_port = htons(LOCAL_PORT);

if(bind(socketInfo, (struct sockaddr *)&local, sizeof(local)) < 0) {
        perror("bind error");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

if(connect(socketInfo, (struct sockaddr *)&remote, sizeof(remote)) < 0) {
        perror("connection error");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

The values of `LOCAL_PORT` and `REMOTE_PORT` would be swapped in the two programs.

Note also that you can get rid of the `setsockopt` call as you don't have two programs open on the same port.